# Difference between Not(condtion) vs !=

Tags: sql, postgresql

What's the difference between `not ([col] = any [collection])` and `[col] != all [collection]` in SQL?

More specifically, in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Have you seen a difference in practice?  I'm pretty sure they are exactly logically equivalent.

Comment: No, but I was wondering if there was any subtle differences in implementation.

Comment: . . In this case, I would be surprised if the implementation were not the same.  That is hard to provide in all cases without analyzing the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. Look at `EXPLAIN`:

```
EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF)
   SELECT * FROM dir WHERE NOT (path = ANY ('{dsa,fds,gfd}'));

                    QUERY PLAN                     
---------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on dir
   Filter: (path <> ALL ('{dsa,fds,gfd}'::text[]))
(2 rows)
```